# url with query params redirecting to / in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

In my application I am using lazy loading. Here is the `app.module.ts`

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "your-app",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: "app/components/your-app/your-app.module#YourAppModule"
    },
    {
        path: "my-app",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: "app/components/my-app/my-app.module#MyAppModule"
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "/"
    }
];
```

and my child module

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: MyAppComponent
    }
];
```

and when I hit `http://localhost:4200/#/my-app?myParam=test`

it redirect me to `http://localhost:4200/#/`

is there any thing missing?

Comment: Just to make sure - are you sure that AuthGuard is not blocking your access to the path? Have you tried to disable this guard just to check if it isn't a cause of the issue?

Comment: @PawelWoroniecki thanks, yes my guard was blocking it

Comment: Glad to see your issue is solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the others if somebody else would be looking for solution in case of similar issues - check your guard as it can block your access to the path. It was also an issue here (see: comments to the question).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
{
     path: "your-app",
     canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     loadChildren: "app/components/your-app/your-app.module#YourAppModule"
}
```

In component.ts file from where user want to redirect --

```
this.router.navigate(['/your-app'], {
      queryParams: {
        myParam: your_value, 
      },
    });
```

Comment: param is optional so user can hit it without the param, in that case?

Comment: Can you please implement it I have used it like this only in my application!

Comment: if i hit the same from the browser adress bar with param it does not work